# Using Foundation 4 framework by Zurb with only CSS. Without SASS/Compass?

Tags: css, codeigniter, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm a beginner in web designing & stackoverflow and I apologize in advance for any silly questions I will be asking

1. I'm using Foundation framework (CSS only version) to design my site without SASS & Compass, and I'm wondering what are the disadvantages besides being unable to build with mixins?
2. Is there any other way to customize Foundation's components without mixins? Because I know it's not recommended to edit foundation.css or any other foundation files.
3. Is it fine if I use Foundation to build pages as View for CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You will be unable to use the full power of SASS, including variables, mixins, nesting, etc. It is definitely more difficult to customize Foundation without using SASS. If you are a beginner to CSS, you should learn the basics before trying to tackle SASS. However, I highly recommend learning it in the near future as it really helps speed up protoyping and layout development.
2. You can override foundation.css with your custom.css file. You can also do some basic customization here and download your own build: http://foundation.zurb.com/download.php#customizeFoundation
3. Sure. Some folks have already created some custom integrations: https://github.com/meridiansoftech/meridian_ci_codebase I have built CakePHP apps with Foundation. Sometimes you have to alter the helpers to output certain HTML to integrate with Foundation or whatever framework you choose to use.